# How do I get the resource name from the resource object?

Tags: c#, winforms, resources, .net-2.0

Say I have an exe added into my resources folder. Now how can I get the name (or even the fullpath from which its linked so that I can still have the file name) of the resource as string?

From `Properties.Resources.myApp` how do I get the `string "myApp"`. ToString() doesnt work. If it is important to embed the file to get the name, I can.

**Edit:** My question is not specifically to get the name of exe resource. But that one generic approach which gives me the name of the resource! For instance what if my resource is a bitmap image? I need to print "Lily" from `Properties.Resources.Lily`. How to achieve this? ToString wont work anyways.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I know this is very old, but the accepted answer is no longer necessarily the best answer. As of C# 6.0 you can just use `nameof(...)`:

```
string resourceName = nameof(Properties.Resources.MyResourceName);
// resourceName == "MyResourceName"
```

Much simpler!

Answer (score 23):

It's quite easy using Linq Expressions:

```
using System.Linq.Expressions;
//...
static string GetNameOf<T>(Expression<Func<T>> property)
{
  return (property.Body as MemberExpression).Member.Name;
}
// Usage:
var s = GetNameOf(() => Properties.Resources.Lily);
```

`s` shoud be `Lily`

Comment: Of course, this will not return the name of the file, but the name of the generated property if you used `ResXFileCodeGenerator` (which, for your question, it seems you do). If you want the actual name of the file, that's impossible: the generated `<resource>Designer.cs` doesn't even have a reference to the filename, and the `.resx` only has it at compile time, not at runtime.

Comment: very nice. How would a C# 2.0 implementation of this be?

Comment: Sorry, I skipped that tag... not in any possibly simple to use way, since you can't pass properties as parameters without Linq, it'd have to be done through magic strings, and that'd mean you already have a string with that name. Your best bet would be extending the ResXFileCodeGenerator and make some string property for each of the resources. One possible way to start would be [this codeproject article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13830/Extended-Strongly-Typed-Resource-Generator) (look at the bottom, it already gives you the resource names as consts).

Comment: [This T4 template](http://blog.baltrinic.com/software-development/dotnet/t4-template-replace-resxfilecodegenerator) could also prove very useful as a starting point, and way easier to suit to your needs than making your own Custom Tool.

Answer (score 2):

With `System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceNames();` you get a list of all ressources in your project.

Now if you want to search for all exe files (I guess you have only one embedded) use the following snippet to get your assembly name.

```
   var ressourceList = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceNames();
   var filename = ressourceList.Where(x => x.EndsWith(".exe")).FirstOrDefault();
```

The string format is `"YourProgram.YourAssemblyName.exe"` so just remove the first part of that string and you have your embedded ressource filename.

Edit: Why don't you enumerate through your ressources and strip the leading namespace + trailing file extensions?

```
 // returns just the names
  public static IEnumerable<String> GetEmbeddedResourceNames()
        {
            var returnList = new List<String>();
            foreach (var res in Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceNames())
            {
                var s = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName();
                returnList.Add(Regex.Replace(res.Replace(s.Name + ".", ""), @"\.[^.]*$", ""));
            }
            return returnList;
        }
```

Edit:

To get a ressource by name, use    `var prop = Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject("YourRessourceNameWithoutExtension");`

Comment: this is a work around. Not the solution to what I ask. I'll edit my question.

Comment: this again, though is closer, gives a list of resource names, now how do I know which file corresponds to which? What if I have more than one exe file embedded. My requirement is for C# 2.0.

Comment: You can't have 2 ressources of the same name (The new would replace the old) - now how should I know which ressource YOU want? If you have 2 exe files App.exe and App1.exe, YOU as programmer must somehow determine which to use,right?

Comment: Thats exactly what I am saying, I might have App1 and App2 in future. As a programmer I know which to use, that's in my question. I know which to use by calling something like GetName(Properties.Resources.App1). I know which to use because I have Properties.Resources.App1 with me. The definition of the function is what I am missing :(

Comment: Check my edit - you can get ressources by name with the ResourceManager. (Don't need the file-extension thats why I rejected the edit)

Comment: How on earth would I get that string? If I know the string, why all this question? It is that string I want!! All I have with me is `Properties.Resources.App1`, now how do I get "YourRessourceNameWithoutExtension" out of it?? Leave it, you are not getting the point. I have read from other sources that it need not be possible.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean you want to have the assembly? Here a little code snippet that get´s you all exe-files from a directory:

```
foreach (string fileName in Directory.GetFiles("./Files"))
{
    FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(fileName);

    if (fileInfo.Extension.Equals(".exe"))
    {
        Assembly pluginAssembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(fileName);

        //...
    }
}
```

Comment: this is a work around. Not the solution to what I ask. I'll edit my question.

Answer (score -1):

When you embed some file in your project resources it will be embed in your executable file when build your project so it's not exist separately from your project executable, it's not exists on your hard drive.
so if you want this myApp.exe in your project folder put it in the project folder then go

- visual studio >>
- Solution explorer >>
- Click Show all files in the upper left corner >>
- MyApp.exe will benn visible >>
- Right click myApp.exe click Include in project >>
- Hit F4 so properties page is shown and focused >>
- set Copy to output directory to "Copy always"

[image][image]

**Now** if you want the path of myApp.exe use :

```
System.IO.Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "myApp.exe");
```

**Update** You should hard code "myApp" because if you go to definition of :

```
Properties.Resources.myApp
```

you will see :

```
internal static byte[] myApp {
        get {
            object obj = ResourceManager.GetObject("myApp", resourceCulture);
            return ((byte[])(obj));
        }
    }
```

It's hard coded !!!!

Comment: This is not at all my question, not anywhere near! See I am not adding my exe as a separate item, but I add it to the resources, so that in future I can embed it finally. My question is how do I get the string name from the resource item, all programmatically. How do during run time I know what is the name of "myApp" ? I cant just hard code "myapp.exe"

Comment: When you use resources there is no FULLPATH, because it's not in hard drive...anyway could explain what exactly you want

Comment: Isnt it in hard drive when I just add, not embed? Also I need not want the fullPath. Just the file name will do.

Comment: I think you're not getting it. It may be hardcoded internally, but how do I get to know what value lies in there? For instance, I set textbox.AccessibleName from the designer as ABC. Now I can get the value ABC from AccessibleName property of the textbox. But it would still be a string value hard coded in the code. How do I get that part of the code which represent the string but is not something coded like "sdsdsd" ??

Comment: In other words, how do I get to open my embedded exe if tomorrow its name is not myApp.exe?