# Launch process (exe file) from resources

Tags: c#, process, resources

I have a compiled exe file which I use to convert images.
It is named convert.exe.
I want to use it within my C# application without being visible in my application folder.
So I thought I could add it as a resource.
The problem is:
How can I launch an external process of an exe file stored in my resources?

Comment: Would writing it to a file first be okay? Because running things directly from memory is tricky and usually pretty pointless.

Comment: I would like to avoid writing it to a file. I don't want it to be accessed/copied by anyone.

Comment: It is not just virus scanners and users that absolutely hate having a process appear from nowhere.  Windows too, it has a core requirement that a process *must* be started from a file on a disk.  Essential to the way it is designed.

Comment: Read this article, it´s kind of the same question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9555679/how-do-i-get-the-resource-name-from-the-resource-object/9599409#9599409

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no way around what Hans Passant said. Practically, in order to run it you must first save it to disk. There are several applications that use this method. One of them is SysInternals [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653). It used to contain the 64 version of the EXE in a resource (I am not 100% sure they still do it this way in the latest version). In any case there are several examples and tutorials on the web for this. [Here is one](http://geekswithblogs.net/TechTwaddle/archive/2009/10/16/how-to-embed-an-exe-inside-another-exe-as-a.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

If you implement some kind of web server in your program (leveraging http.sys), you can run the executable from a unc path that resolves (via windwows webdav client)  to the url.