# Get license file from Resources folder in C#

Tags: c#, resources, relative-path, license-key

I have a license file that I need to access at runtime. I have added license file to the resources folder. I need to call a method on the run time which will look for the license file.

```
test.CheckLicenseFile("PathOflicenseFile");
```

I would like to know how can i get this path at runtime? Also please tell me what properties should I set for this license file i.e content, embedded resource etc, and copy to output or not. Please note that my project is of type windows control library(usercontrol) i.e. it creates a .dll file?

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
Properties.Resources.PathOflicenseFile;
```

if its added to Resources. Or more precisely you could do:

```
test.CheckLicenseFile(Properties.Resources.PathOflicenseFile);
```

Edit:

For your second part, you need not copy the license file to ouput, if it is gonna be embedded. Copying to output is meaningless for a dll (Unless you really want to modify the license file outside the dll)

Edit:
As I understand your question more now, there is no way out there to get its original path in file system of resources files. One thing you could do is embed the resource file, then extract it to a certain location upon request to a temp folder and then locate that path to your `check` function.

Comment: Ok, you mean i should set the property as embedded resource? What about Copy to Output Directory? What should i set?

Comment: You need not copy to ouput, if it is gonna be embedded. Copying is meaningless for a dll

Comment: Error'Namespace.Properties.Resources' does not contain a definition for 'License.lic'

Comment: That probably means you have not added it to your resources folder yet. Could you tell how have you added it?

Comment: Right clicked on the Resources Folder, Add existing item, Added licences.lic. Then set the property build Action as "Embedded Resource".

Comment: @MujtabaBhat that's not the way to add. Instead you should click open "properties", then there you see a resources.resx which you can open by double clicking. it is there where you have to add. You would see properties just under the project node in your solution explorer. Select Add resource> existing item and there you go :)

Comment: Error: Cannot implicitly convert type 'byte[]' to 'string'. Got this error. Then tried to use Properties.Resources.License.ToString() but it didn't get correct path.

Comment: @MujtabaBhat why do you want the path of the file? When embedding it to your dll, the relative path to access that lic file is what is provided in my code in the answer. Do you want the physical path in the file system? Why do you want it first of all? Tell us what exactly you wanna do, that would help us better in tackling your problem

Comment: Yes, i need the physical path. Actually i am using a third party ocx in my user control. Hence inorder to activate it requires path of the license file as paramemter to a function called CheckLicenseFile("Path"). The path should be string.

Comment: @MujtabaBhat There is no way out there to get its original path in file system for resources files. See this link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9555679/how-do-i-get-the-resource-name-from-the-resource-object

Now I understood your requirement. One thing you could do is embed the resource file, then extract it to a certain location upon request to a temp folder and then locate that path to your check function. Wanna go the hard path? Thats never a bad thing to do at all

Comment: Thanks for the reply... Now what i am planning to do is include the license.lic file in the set up. So when i install the dll the license.lic will be copied to the application folder. Then i can provide the application folder path to that function. Do you know how to get the path where the application is installed?

Comment: @MujtabaBhat nice tht u figured it out. Its time for u to accept some answers.. (not this, but generally)