# Accessing location of embedded XML file

Tags: c#

I have added an XML file to a Windows form project by right clicking on resources | add item and I have set the properties to embedded resource, do not copy. I need to copy the XML file to a location on the target disk but how do I get the location of the XML file from the embedded resources to use with File.Copy

Thanks.

Comment: GetManifestResourceStream

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get the resource name from the resource object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9555679/how-do-i-get-the-resource-name-from-the-resource-object)

Answer (score 0):

Use [System.Reflection.Assembly.GetManifestResourceNames](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.getmanifestresourcenames(v=vs.110).aspx). It will return a list of all of the resources within the assembly, and you can use it (in the Visual Studio immediate window) to determine what string you need to pass to get the resource you want.

From there, you need to use [System.Reflection.Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.getmanifestresourcestream(v=vs.110).aspx). To get a stream of the file. Then you can use the `CopyTo` method to copy it to a `FileStream` of a new file of your choosing.